# Apache HttpClient 4.0. Weird behavior

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm using Apache HttpClient 4.0 for my web crawler. The behavior i found strange is: i'm trying to get page via HTTP GET method and getting response about 404 HTTP error. But if i try to get that page using browser it's done successfully.

Details:
1. I upload multipart form to server this way:

```
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://[host here]/in.php");

    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    entity.addPart("method", new StringBody("post"));
    entity.addPart("key", new StringBody("223fwe0923fjf23"));
    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File("photo.jpg"), "image/jpeg");
    entity.addPart("file", fileBody);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);       
    HttpEntity result = response.getEntity();

    String responseString = "";
    if (result != null) {
        InputStream inputStream = result.getContent();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while(inputStream.read(buffer) > 0)
            responseString += new String(buffer);

        result.consumeContent();
    }
```

Uppload succefully ends.

2. I'm getting some results from web server:

   ```
       HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://[host here]/res.php?key="+myKey+"&action=get&id="+id);

       HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   ```

I'm getting ClientProtocolException while execute method run. I was debugging this situation with log4j. Server answers "404 Not Found". But my browser loads me that page with no problem.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked if your browser is returning a cached page?

Comment: log4j tells this:

DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire] >> "GET /res.php?key=sadf3f3f34f4f43f4f&action=get&id=89122037[0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0].....

many nulls at the end. May be it's a problem cause? If so, how can i eliminate it?

Comment: Did you try switching from HTTP 1.1 to 1.0 or the other way around? I think I remember vaguely that httpclient had some problems with some servers (how it communicates), causing the server to return 404.

Comment: Looks like the value in your id variable is bogus. Does it really contain the nulls at the end?

Comment: Thank you for quick answers.

disown, I've just tried to use HTTP 1.0 but HTTP server didn't answer at all.

jitter, no, id variable doesn't contain nulls. It's a regular string like "12341235".

Comment: toolkit, i'm sure the result isn't from cache.

Comment: The second snippet returns a 404 as well as the first? One's using post, the other get. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Have you tried `URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8")` on your `HttpGet` method?

Answer (score 0):

I have to note the problem isn't concerned with web server. If i don't add FileBody to multipart form data, exception doesn't occure, all goes fine with no HTTP 404.